# When does an algebraic extension ring preserve properties (such as UFD, Euclidean, GCD, Bèzout or PID) of the original ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

Assume $A$ is a commutative ring with unity and a domain. Let $A[k]$ be a generic non-trascendental extension of $A$. Let the element $k$ be such that, for a given polynomial $p(x)$ in $A[x]$, we have that $p(k)=0$ and for any other $g(x)$ such that $g(k)=0$, $g(x)$ must be a multiple of $p(x)$ in $A[x]$ (i.e. $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $k$).

It seems to me that certain properties of $A[k]$ are solely based upon properties of the polynomial $p(x)$ and of the ring $A$ itself. But it seems like there are very few characterisations of this kind.

A question that arises is: given $A$ is Euclidean (or PID, UFD, Bèzout, GCD) for which polynomials $p(x)$ I have that $A[k]$ is Euclidean (or PID, UFD, Bèzout, GCD). Essentially, I am interested on when does the extension conserve a given property. I would also be interested to see if there are maybe some (non-trivial) necessary or sufficient conditions to have the inheritance of said property onto the extension ring.

There are some properties that are easy to characterize, for instance if $A$ is a field, then we have:

$$
p(x)\text{ is irreducible } \iff A[k]\text{ is a field }.
$$

But I was wondering if there are more, maybe more complex characterisations.

Comment: Note that for $A=\Bbb Z$, this includes the question which quadratic number field have class number 1. This was solved by some nontrivial and specific methods in the imaginary quadratic case and is still open in the real quadratic case. So a general answer even in the case $A=\Bbb Z$ seems to be wide open, if not completely hopeless.